# Android Google Sign in and automated email sender

Tags: android, email, gmail, google-plus, google-signin

Recently I have tried to make auto Gmail sender. It was using user login and password, and low access to be sent from other apps to send Gmail.

Now I have integrated Google Sign in button.
I want to merge them and send Gmail automatically but without giving me password.

Is it possible to get the password from sign in? Or it should be done in other way?

Comment: Don't ask for a gmail user password! Use the gmail scope and gmail APIs instead

Comment: Steven Soneff can you send me example of gmail scopes I have seen it in developer.google.com but I cant find the use of it.